# Le titre de l'hymne européen n'est-il pas mal traduit en français ?

Tags: traduction

Passons sur le fait que l'hymne européen n'a en fait ni titre ni paroles, *stricto sensu*, en raison du multi-linguisme ; mais il faut bien pouvoir le désigner autrement que par une périphrase.

Traditionnellement, on dit en français "l'Hymne à la Joie".

1- En fait, c'est une ode (poème chanté) et non un hymne (chant à la gloire d'un dieu à l'origine, puis d'une nation). Admettons que ce soit un hymne à la gloire de l'Europe.

2- Bien plus important : Schiller a conçu initialement son poème comme ode à la liberté (*Freiheit* en allemand).

C'est évident d'après les paroles, qui n'ont aucun rapport avec la joie (*Freude* en allemand). Mais parfaitement cohérentes avec l'idée des bienfaits qu'apporte la liberté à toute l'humanité - la joie n'en a guère besoin : pourquoi louer la joie ?.

La substitution des deux mots est très facile en allemand (même longueur, même accentuation, sonorités voisines, et les deux premières lettres sont identiques).
Elle permettait de passer astucieusement d'un chant proprement révolutionnaire, dont l'esprit est transcrit dans la musique de Beethoven, à une élégie assez banale.

**Ne devrait-on donc pas traduire en français par "Ode à la liberté" ?**

Comment: L'hymne européen est sans paroles officielles. S'il est donc bien un arrangement de la mise en musique de l'*Ode an die Freude* de Schiller par Beethoven, ce n'est qu'un lien indirect. Quand à l'affirmation selon laquelle l'ode était originellement à la liberté, ni [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ode_to_Joy) ni moi n'avons pu en trouver de preuve sérieuse. Il semble donc qu'il n'y a pas de problème.

Comment: Pourquoi ne pas en avoir fait une réponse ? Par ailleurs, tant qu’à pointer sur Wikipédia, autant pointer sur [la francophone](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ode_à_la_joie), où l’on pourra remarquer que le titre est plutôt traduit par « Ode à la joie », et apprendre que le titre allemand évoque bien la *Freude* plutôt que la *Freiheit*, qui était pourtant bien le sujet de l’ode, et ce par volonté de l’auteur.

Comment: L'ode a été écrite en 1785, époque où en Europe on aspirait plus à la liberté que l'on avait de motifs pour se réjouir. Beethoven a écrit la musique progressivement et beaucoup plus tard, quand le mot "liberté" était dangereux. Pour le reste, je m'en suis remis à diverses sources qui me semblent cohérentes, n'étant pas historien. Quant au texte, il n'a pas grand sens ni grande portée si on lit "joie", mais est cohérent et révolutionnaire pour "liberté". L'entrée du chœur de la IXème fait-elle penser à la joie ?

Comment: Ou bien parlons un peu vrai et appelons-le *Ode au libre-échange* ? ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hymne est rattaché à la nation aux travers des très officiels hymnes nationaux et fédéraux.

Beaucoup connaissent l'air de celui du voisin sans en connaître les paroles.

Il n'y a donc pas de raison de ne pas appeler *hymne* une mélodie sans parole, mais avec une intention proclamée : la joie ; notons que la joie est une phase émotionnelle cyclique, peut-être  eût-il été préférable d'y trouver *l'harmonie* ou *l'équilibre* (mouvement d'apparence immobile ou stable qui se réajuste continuellement à la réalité).

Le *chant de la Liberté* est encore plus difficile sans parole.

L'*air de l'harmonie* sinise l'ambiance, pourquoi ne pas rassembler les états sur l'**Air de la joie** ou plus simplement sur l'**Air européen** ?